# formulatext in functionxform in pmml - Keep value as is

Tags: r, pmml

Is there a way to keep Species values as is after evaluating an expression?
I want to create a derived column where if species is setosa then assign -9 and if not then return the original value. "keep as is" is a made up expression. Thanks.

```
irisBox <- FunctionXform(WrapData(iris),origFieldName="Species",
                         newFieldName="Species.Setosa",
                         formulaText="if (Species == 'setosa') {-9} else {keep as is}")
head(irisBox$data)
```

By the way, the operation below works for numerical variables such as Petal.Width  -

```
irisBox <- FunctionXform(irisBox,origFieldName="Petal.Width",
                         newFieldName="trial",
                         formulaText="if (Petal.Width == -9999999) {0} else Petal.Width ")
```

However, if I specify else Species for "Species" column then it does not work.

Comment: any comments guys if not answers? I think PMML's R package is a great resource however some of the basic things such as this are not very well explained in the vignette. Much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Did you find something ?